# Vaadin Flow Access Current RouterLayout (from anywhere)

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

We have a RouterLayout class as a frame for the rest of our application, which includes different non-changing components, including a notification element, that needs to stay visible throughout navigation.

```
@CssImport("./styles/shared-styles.css")
public class MainFrame extends Composite<VerticalLayout> implements RouterLayout, PageConfigurator, AfterNavigationObserver {
    
    // central Notification that persists throughout navigation
    private Notification notification;


    // other stuff....

}
```

We're now trying to show this notification from anywhere within our code, so that all views, components and subcomponents are able to show a simple notification.

Unfortunately I'm not aware of an easy way to access the notification that exists inside the RouterLayout, because we can't access the layout level of the current UI. Putting the notification inside a view (router content) doesn't work, because it gets destroyed on navigation. Trying to use the event bus doesn't work, because event listeners inside the routerlayout won't be called when fired from inside the router content (as far as I've tested).

What we hope to achieve is to have a simple access class in a static fashion that is able to access the notification component of the currently set router.

```
public static void showNotification(String text) {
    // something like this
    MainFrame frame = ((MainFrame)UI.getCurrent().getRouterLayout()).showNotification(text);
}
```

Basicly we're unaware of an easy way to communicate with the currently set layout of the current UI from anywhere inside of our application, similar to `UI.getCurrent()`. Is there a way to achieve something like this?

Comment: Your question is practically duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67783918/vaadin-refer-to-mainlayout-from-routerlayout/67784161#67784161 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180043/how-to-use-variables-methods-of-router-layout-class-in-another-class-in-vaadin

Comment: If your application is using Spring Boot or Java EE CDI I would recommend to refactor the shared part in managed bean and autowire / inject it everywhere needed.

Comment: @TatuLund if I see it correctly the first question is about spreading infos accross multiple tabs of the same session, while the second one is talking about accessing the RouterLayout through the next lower element. While my question is very similar in the topic, I was more interested about a conventient way to have UI-scoped access to the current RouterLayout from anywhere inside the application, not just the next child of it. While traversing is a (rather dirty) way to do it here as well, I'd much rather have a solution with a static function access just like UI.getCurrent()

Comment: Yes, they are different aspects of the same story. And un-fortunatelly there is now fool proof way for UI-scoped access. You can piggy bag data to UI wtih ComponentUtil as described by Leif, but that wont work if you need PreserveOnRefresh. The only neat solution is Spring or CDI using RouterScoped with MainLayout as scope owner.

Comment: Leifs aproach did it for us, right now we don't have elements on the main frame that need to be preserved on refresh, they should just not be lost throughout navigation. So as described we link the MainFrame to the current UI and can access the currently shown Frame statically from anywhere within the application. Maybe better options will come in the future, but for now we're satisfied with the given approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't directly tie this to the concept of navigation and router layouts. What you have is functionality that is a "singleton" within the scope of a UI instance.

If using Spring or CDI, then this is natural to define as a managed bean in the UI scope that you can inject wherever needed.

Another alternative is to base the logic on `UI.getCurrent()`. The `ComponentUtil` method in Flow has `setData` and `getData` methods that you can use to attach your own custom instances to a specific component instance. You could thus do something like this:

```
ComponentUtil.getData(UI.getCurrent(), MainFrame.class).showNotification("Hello");
```